# Compare time in php with current time

Tags: php

I am trying to compare time got from url:

```
$expireTime = $_GET['st']; //the parameter is made like: time() + 3600;

if(time() <= $expireTime){
    print_r('valid time');
} else {
    throw new Exception("Time expired");
}
```

but it is always time expired.

Comment: Having you tried echoing `$_GET['st']` to make sure it's what you think it is?

Comment: It either means your `$_GET['st']` value is not what you want it to be OR your time has expired...Does it work if you set `$expireTime` directly in the same code? Like this: `$expireTime = time() + 3600;`?

Answer (score 0):

Please use following.

```
$expireTime = $_GET['st']; //the parameter is made like: time() + 3600;
$expiretime = strtotime($expireTime);
if(time() <= $expiretime){
print_r('valid time');
} 
else {
throw new Exception("Time expired");
}
```